# How Do I Prevent Migration from Attempting to Drop a View?

Tags: grails

I have a view created that I'm binding to a domain-class.

How do I get database-migration to ignore this view so it doesn't attempt to drop it every time `dbm-gorm-diff` is ran?

Comment: Drop the view, then create a change set that creates the view, run the migration. Now it's a part of the database migration plan. It shouldn't try and drop it.

Comment: I did create the view via a changeset and was successful, but the command still attempts to drop it and create a table instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ignoredObjects` config setting ([docs here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/configuration.html)), e.g.

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.ignoredObjects = ['dont_drop_me_bro']
```

Comment: Updated for 3.0.x: use `grails.plugin.databasemigration.excludeObjects` http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/3.0.x/index.html#configuration